# How do I do async work in a function and then return a value from that function when finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, return

I am using a library that requires me to pass in a "validate" function. In this function I need to validate some input and then return `true` if it passes or `false` if it fails.

The problem is that I need to check if a user exists in the database for this validation function and Mongoose invokes a callback with the result. If I `return` within the callback it's just returning from the callback function not my validate function.

```
...
validate: function (username) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (user)
            // User exists so we should return false from the validate function
        else
            // User does not exist so we should return true from validate.
    });
}
```

I'm trying to use the async library to solve this, but async also invokes a callback when its done!

Comment: round peg in a square hole, won't work. you can fake async, but you can't fake sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

*For all intents and purposes* JavaScript is single-threaded. Yes, you have callbacks and presence of multi-threading (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`, event callbacks) but you can't jump out of a callback and come back in the same function.

My advice is to try to pre-process this validation before `validate` is called so you have a "yay or ney" result to work within within `validate`.

Comment: Dang. I don't have the value to search for in the database until this function is called. In what way should the library be modified so that this work can be done? I will modify it and submit a pull request if I can but I'm not sure how I would change this behavior. Should one of the arguments passed to the validate function be a `done` callback or something?

Comment: I don't know the work-flow, but you either perform the lookup while (or just after) the value is being changed (so at time of validation you have a checksum value), or introduce a pre-step that the user needs to execute before validate is available. (I know you're in node, but a for instance would be the submit button isn't enabled until the user presses "check" next to the username field)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [promises](http://howtonode.org/promises) to achieve this.

```
var q = require('q');

validate: function (username) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err){return deferred.reject(err)}
      if (user)
        // User exists so we should return false from the validate function
        deferred.resolve(false);
      else
        // User does not exist so we should return true from validate.
        deferred.resolve(true)
    });
    return deferred.promise;
 }
```

and then use the validate function as below.

```
validate('username').then(function(result){
  if (result)
     console.log('user doesnt exist');
  else
     console.log('user exists');

}, function(err){
   if(err)
      console.log('Error', err); 
})
```

Comment: I can't return a promise. The library expects true or false to be returned from the validate function.